# UML Tool for JavaEE-applications, with good Annotation/EJB-support

Tags: jakarta-ee, uml, ejb

I'm looking for a good UML tool (free or at least available as a Trial, availability as an Eclipse- or Netbeans-plugin would also be nice) to visualize the class hierarchy (doesn't have to be strict UML) inside an JavaEE-application.

It should have a decent EJB/annotation support (most important feature). I googled around and found this screenshot: [link](http://www.eclipsedownload.com/pictures/MusicStoreEJB3.png) which is what close to what i want, but i can't find out how the tool used for this screenshot is called.

Anyone knows how the tool on this screenshot is called?
What tools do experienced EJB-developers prefer to visualize their classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseUML Omondo has the annotatiion support. 
Have a look if you can pay the license.

Comment: Yeah i guess this is the tool from the screenshot. Seems quite okay. Can generate Classmodel out of existing Java EJBs like . 30-day trial is enough for my project. Thanks!

Comment: The bad thing about Omondo is that it only shows EJB and Entity-related annotations. Other annotations are not included in class diagrams (e.g. Weld-Beans, Security-related annotations)

Comment: All annotations are included and not just Entity. The test is to reverse an existing code and you will see the annotations.
The problem is that this feature is only available in Eclipse 3.6 which is a private build for paid customer. So that's too bad..

Answer (score 0):

The free [MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/) Reverse Engineering Framework (main reverse engineering tool in the umbrella of the Eclipse Modeling Project) can deal with the reverse engineering of Java EE applications. See also a short intro to Modisco here: http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/short-introduction-modisco-model-driven-software-modernization-framework or here: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/07/introduction-modisco

(and/or let me know if you have any question)

Comment: Hmm from what i see MoDisco isn't a tool to create a nice-looking class diagram from a (simple) JEE-project in <=30 minutes? ;) Or am i missing something? I don't need to re-engineer nor any model-driven-related stuff

Comment: The reverse is very basic and not even 50% of critical information are reversed into the model. I mean reverse at multiple package level, show associaiton between classes not the same package, dependencies etc...Only inheritance are ok.
I don't also see java annotation reverse because this feature is not implemented in this project. Did I miss something ?

Comment: MoDisco is a full-fledged reverse engineering process based on OMG standards like KDM. This means that can be configured and adapted to any scenario (including the JEE to UML) but on the other hand it is true that it is not "plug&play" so you´ll need more than 30 minutes to learn how to use it